# Cannot install IE11 "did not finish" ... out of ideas

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, internet-explorer-11

I'm just finishing cleaning up a laptop with a pretty bad malware infection.  I ended running a repair install of Windows 7 Home Premium x64 and everything seems to be working well, except for one last thing: no matter how or how many times I attempt to install IE11 (using the Offline installer), it invariably results in the totally useful "...did not finish installing." error.

After reviewing, `c:\Windows\IE11_main.log`, this is the only error:

`0x00009C59 (40025) - The neutral cab failed to install`

No results on a search for that have been fruitful.  Help?

**EDIT** ... I don't think I ever solved this.  Based on my worklogs, it was probably due to malware.  I probably gave up and installed Firefox.

Comment: A lot of (not all obviously) IT professionals recommend reformatting after a virus - to kill it forever because there are so many things that could be left over - although the virus may be gone, removal has probably restored previous settings!

Comment: Do you have IE10 installed?  have you ran `sfc /scannow` yet?

Comment: @DaveRook: Obviously, that would clear it up, but I generally try avoid that last resort if at all possible.  I'm an independent contractor providing support for small businesses, so I don't have recent or even factory images for everyone.  Data backup/restore and software reinstalls are time consuming and costly :)

Comment: @Ramhound: currently, it's IE9.  I'll try the system file checker, thanks.

Comment: Try to download the Offline installer, and see if that solves your issue: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-11-worldwide-languages

Comment: @JSanchez: sorry, I should have mentioned; I am already using the offline installer.

Comment: Assuming you once fixed this: can you please post an answer for future visitors?

Comment: @Arjan: lol, you're gonna make me dig, eh?  I'll have to look back through my worklogs and update my post.

Answer (score 0):

I have win 7 64 bit. Had ie8. Learnt that I needed ie11 to get update for win 10. Every time I tried to install, the install would fail at the end and would give a could not finish installation error. Tried every trick I could find on the net. After racking my brain for 4 hours, I found something which finally worked. Changing the clock time to 1-1-2012 did the trick. Relieved beyond measure. Hope it helps.